# Grails binding one to one associations

Tags: grails, data-binding, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-controller

When you generate grails views, grails looks at your relationships and generates the right html for your form data to be automatically binded to the back end domain. For one to one associations grails creates a drop down list.

However, you might not want to present that property as a drop down list but something more custom (for example a text field with autocomplete). As soon as you do that the value that comes to the controller from that field, comes in as a String and you have to first:

1. Clear errors
2. Perform a findBy based on a given param and assign it to the property of the domain

I really want to avoid doing findBys in the controller as much as possible because it seems like I am doing logic/things that should not go there. The controller should delegate to the Service layer. It is not clear to me from the grails documentation how would I do that by using **bindData** which seems to work really well with String, date, Integer properties etc.. but I do not see how bindData is used for properties that are other domains.

I also really want to avoid passing the **params** object to the Service layer as it seems less reusable (or maybe not, correct me if I am wrong). I guess that I do not like how it looks semantically. I would prefer the first over the second:

```
@Transactional
class WithdrawService {

    def addWithdraw(Withdraw withdraw) {

        //perform business logic here
    }

    def createWithdraw(Map params){

        //perform business logic here
    }
}
```

Let's take the following example:

```
class Withdraw {

   Person person
   Date withdrawDate

}
```

and the parent lookup table

```
class Person {

   String name
   String lastName

   static constraints = {
   }


   @Override
   public String toString() {
     return "$name $lastName"
   }
```

}

In order for the bind to happen automatically without any extra work grails passes in the following request params to automatically bind the one to one:

1. person.id
2. a person map with the id.

   [person.id:2, person:[id:2], withdrawDate:date.struct, withdrawDate_month:11, create:Create, withdrawDate_year:2015, withdrawDate_day:10, action:save, format:null, controller:withdraw]

## What is the best way to go about this?

1. Pass two hidden fields that look exactly like this: **person.id:2, person:[id:2]** that get populated as a result of the Ajax call that populates the autocomplete?
2. In the controller do a Person.findBySomeKnownProperty(params.someKnownValue)
3. Or any other approach?

Comment: Pass `person.id` as a part of your parameters and the binding will happen automatically. That's the correct way. So #1.

Comment: That did it. I also had to rename the person textfield to something else. Otherwise, it seemed like the person had preference over the person.id field and it would not pass validation.